# How do I make use of findIterate in eBean with a raw sql query?

Tags: ebean

Let's say I have the following code:

```
String sql = "select c.id, c.name from Company c left join Tag t on c.id=t.company_id where c.state='PUBLISHED'";

List<SqlRow> sqlRows =
                Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql).setMaxRows(4000000).findList();
for(SqlRow row : sqlRows) {
    // Do cool stuff
}
```

`findList()` will then load everything up to memory which isn't what I really want in this case.

I saw that `Query<T>` has `findIterate()` but `Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql)` returns `SqlQuery` and that doesn't have `findIterate()`. So how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess RFTM is in place here, or take 5 minutes of and then return to the problem. 
This is how I did it:

**ServiceClass:**

```
String sql = "Select c.id, c.name from Company c left join Tag t on c.id=t.company_id where c.state='PUBLISHED'";    

RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder
            .parse(sql)
            .columnMapping("c.name", "word")
            .columnMappingIgnore("c.id")
            .create();

Query<SearchWord> query = Ebean.find(SearchWord.class);
QueryIterator<SearchWord> iterator = query
            .setMaxRows(4000000)
            .setRawSql(rawSql)
            .findIterate();
try {
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next()
        // do magic stuff in here
    }
} finally {
    iterator.close();
}
```

**SearchWord**

```
@Entity
public class SearchWord {

    private String word;
    private String type;

    public SearchWord() {
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```